# How to initialize object with property of array

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
interface MenuItemRefsProps {
    current: React.Component;
    tag: number;
    route: string;
};

let tvDrawerObject: {
    menuItemRefs: MenuItemRefsProps[];
};
tvDrawerObject = { menuItemRefs: [] };
```

But my eslint complains, that

> 'tvDrawerObject' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead.

If I use const for 'tvDrawerObject' I need to initialize it. I don't know how to do it. I tried something like this:

```
const tvDrawerObject: {
    menuItemRefs: MenuItemRefsProps[] = [];
};
```

Then another complain arise:

> A type literal property cannot have an initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is, initialize the `const` right away:

```
const tvDrawerObject: {
    menuItemRefs: MenuItemRefsProps[]
} = { menuItemRefs: [] };
```

The reason for this is because `const`'s should not be able to change after initialization.

Comment: It is not working. Red color is under `[]` after equation mark on second line.

Comment: But if I change it to `const tvDrawerObject: {
  menuItemRefs: MenuItemRefsProps[];
} = { menuItemRefs: [] };` it looks ok.

Comment: Ahhh. I missed that, will edit the answer, we shouldn't try to initialize when specifying a type.